# Rewriting $-\sin\theta+i\cos\theta$ and $-\sin\theta-i\cos\theta$ as complex exponentials

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I have found myself with the expression

$$
-\sin(\theta) + i \cos(\theta)
$$

and

$$
-\sin(\theta) - i \cos(\theta) 
$$

I would like to simplify these ... presumably using Euler... but I can't figure out how.

The only forms I have ever uses are the standard $e^{ix} = \cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta)$ and $e^{-ix} = \cos(\theta) - i \sin(\theta)$

After reading through the Wikipedia article, the only instance of such an expression is regarding proving the Euler formula via polar coordinates, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#Using_polar_coordinates

Comment: Factor $i=e^{i\pi/2}$, use the usual formula and add powers.

Comment: $ie^{i\theta} = i(\cos \theta + i\sin\theta) = i\cos \theta - \sin \theta.$

Comment: these are derivatives of $e^{\pm i\theta}$ and remember that derivating is the same as adding $\frac{\pi}2$ to the variable (i.e. same as multiplying by $i$).

Comment: @DougM thank you! :) feel free to change to an answer!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Calculate $$e^{i(\theta+\pi/2)}$$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* Multiply the expressions by $$1=\frac{i}{i}=-ii$$ like so $-iiE=-i(iE),$ where $E$ is some expression.